# How do I bind to the preferred size of a ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollview

I have a WPF `ListView` that should be extended with an always visible footer.
The footer shall behave like a header and should not be scrolled away.
The following XAML uses an external `ScrollViewer` linked to code behind to steer the ScrollViewer of the ListView:

```
<Window x:Class="LayoutTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="125" Width="176">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <ListView Name="L" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListViewItem Content="Brown brownie with a preference for white wheat."/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Red Redish with a taste for oliv olives."/>
      </ListView>
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
        <!-- Would like to bind Rectangle.Width to the preferred width of L -->
        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="500" Fill="Red"/>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the code behind this looks like this:

```
private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var bottomScrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
  var listScrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(L) as ScrollViewer;
  if (listScrollViewer != null && bottomScrollViewer != null )
    listScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( bottomScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset );
}
```

`GetScrollViewer()` is defined like this (but unimportant):

```
public static DependencyObject GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
  if (depObj is ScrollViewer)
  { return depObj; }
  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
  {
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
    var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
    if (result == null) { continue; }
    else { return result; }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The `ScrollViewer` of `ListView` obviously knows about the preferred width of its children.
The problem is that I cant find a way to bind to that width. So here it is:

How do I bind `Rectangle.Width` to the preferred size of the `ListView`?

Or, alternatively, how do I include a footer in the `ListView` that is always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind against `ExtentWidth` of your `ScrollViewer`. According to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.extentwidth.aspx, it's a `DependencyProperty`. Mind that you need the `ScrollViewer` of your `ListView`, not the additional one you are creating below the list view.

You can use your `GetScrollViewer` function to find the `ScrollViewer` on the `ListView`. Of course, you'll need to set the binding in the code-behind. Something like that:

```
Binding b = new Binding("ExtentWidth") { Source = GetScrollViewer(L) };
rect.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty, b);
```

Comment: your binding setting is quite interesting - I didnt know that one could mess around with its contents by specifying code in {}. Is there a name for that? Currently it doesn't work for me - the scrollbar is not appearing. Debugging now.

Comment: Strange -- what is its width? (You can look up using [Snoop utility](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: Well, and you can debug bindings by specifying a dummy converter (and setting a breakpoint in its `Convert` method).

Comment: The googleable name should be "setting binding in code-behind"

Comment: The "ViewportWidth" is bound to the shown width of the content. What I want here is the "ExtentWidth". Setting that in the binding makes above answer work. @Vlad if you change your answer I mark it as solution.

Comment: Ah, I see :) Nice, so I'll correct the answer for the future readers.