# Fit Columns to Listview width

Tags: wpf, listview, column-width

I want the columns of listview to fill all the listview.
How do I do it ?

```
            <ListView  Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="1"  />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="300"  Header="Details" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Any Ideas,
Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 0):

Try Width="**", or if u want your first column to be 2/5 of the listview and the other 3/5 try on the first Width="2*" and the second Width="3*"
there should be an * after 2 in the Width, i don't know why it isn't shown

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309249/listview-gridviewcolumn-width

Comment: I do not like that hack. Do you know any grid in WPF that the last line can be filled and fit the container width ?

Comment: DataGrid will work with * for width     
        <DataGrid >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>     
        <DataGrid >

Comment: GridViewColumn does not allow Width="*"