# Gripper in WPF gridview not expanding to the entire width of Listview

Tags: wpf

The gridview gripper is not expanding till the complete header.  It is somehow stays half on the header.  The gridview is a type of Listview.View and the entire listview is present in

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinition>
<ListView Grid.Column=0>
<GridView>
<GridViewColumn/>
</GridView>
```

This is the basic structure.  I don't know why the gripper in the header is not expanding properly so as to fully occupy the width of the gridviewcolumn.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0">
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[ListView.GridViewColumn (*) width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309249/listview-gridviewcolumn-width)

Basically what they do is to have a hidden grid with an auxiliary width.

Try it out :)